# Generating a new array if a certain criteria is met (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic

I have an array of users who all need to be added to a group array. If the the group array has less than 3 users, i want to add the user to that group array. If the group array already has 3 user, I want to push the current group array to another array that collects all the groups and start another new group array for the next 3 users until there are no users.

---

Error -

`let group[i] = [];`

`Unexpected token [`

---

I have been racking my brains trying to figure this out. Maybe staring at the screen for too long.

This is what i have been trying with different variations but the console is not impressed -

```
function createGroups(totalPeople){
  let i = 1
  let group[i] = [];
  let array = totalPeople

  totalPeople.map((user) => {

    if(group[i] =< 3){
      group[i].push(user)
    }else{
      array.push(group[i]);
      i++
    }
  })
};
```

totalPeople is an array created earlier in my code and this is the only part of the file that is not running as intended. Any help with a method on how to do this or suggestions on fixing this code would be of great help! thank you!

Comment: You don't need the `'let'`.  Just `group[i] = [];`. `let` is for declaring new variables.

Comment: ... as long as `group` is already declared as an array. `let group = []; group[i] = [];`

Comment: why this line let group[i] = []; ?

Comment: so apart from that the code looks pretty solid?
Thank you for the reply by the way!

Comment: The logic seems weird, because you're comparing an array to a number in your if condition : `if(group[i] =< 3)`

Comment: ahh shit its supposed to have .length and its supposed to be  <= instead of =<

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize  group as an array:

```
let i = 1
  let group = [] // Initialize as an array
   group[i] = [];
  let array = totalPeople

  totalPeople.map((user) => {

    if(group[i] =< 3){
      group[i].push(user)
    }else{
      array.push(group[i]);
      i++
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code :

```
function createGroups(totalPeople){
  let i = 1
  let group[i] = []; // issue #1
  let array = totalPeople

  totalPeople.map((user) => {

    if(group[i] =< 3){ // issues #2 and #3 
      group[i].push(user)
    }else{
      array.push(group[i]); // issue #4 
      i++; // issue #5 
    }
  })
};
```

**Issue #1 :**

You need to define `group` as an array before adding an index.

```
let group = []; 
group[i] = [];
```

**Issue #2 :**

Looks like you meant to compare `group[i].length` and 3

**Issue #3 :**

Use `<=` instead of `=<` to compare your numbers. Also, if you compare the length with `<=` 3, you'll have 4 people per group. Because the first index in arrays is 0.

**Issue #4 :**

You are pushing to `array`, which is a reference to `totalPeople`. Is this what you meant? Because I doubt it will produce the expected results. You may want to initialize an empty array and push your group[i] array in it. And then, return that new array. It's usually a good practice in functionnal programming to return a new array and not modify the one passed as a parameter.

**Issue #5 :**

If you increment `i`, you need to initialize `group[i]` as an array, otherwise you won't be able to push in it when comes the next loop iteration.

**Differnet logic :**

Now that you fixed the issues in your code, here's a Snippet showing another way to do it using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) :

```js
const totalPeople = ["Joe", "Jack", "Jerry", "Jane", "Mary", "Billy", "Vicky", "Bobby"];

const groupsOfThree = totalPeople.reduce((accumulator, currentPerson, index) => {

  // pushing the current person in the topest group in the accumulator 
  accumulator[accumulator.length-1].push(currentPerson);

  // if it's the 3rd person, we're pushing the an empty group in the accumulator
  if (index % 3 === 2) {
    accumulator.push([]);
  }

  return accumulator;
}, [[]]); // the initial value of the accumulator will be an array containing an empty group

console.log(groupsOfThree);
```